# way to fetch data and time from openweathermap api?

Tags: javascript, html, api, fetch-api, openweathermap

I was trying to fetch datas from openweathermap api in JS for my website
but in the json file some parameters are missing
like sunrise sunset date timezone etc (btw using free api)
below is the json format of the api call

```
{
"message": "accurate",
"cod": "200",
"count": 1,
"list": [
{
"id": 1275004,
"name": "Kolkata",
"coord": {
"lat": 22.5697,
"lon": 88.3697
},
"main": {
"temp": 28.97,
"feels_like": 28.49,
"temp_min": 28.35,
"temp_max": 28.97,
"pressure": 1009,
"humidity": 39
},
"dt": 1646658548,
"wind": {
"speed": 2.06,
"deg": 320
},
"sys": {
"country": "IN"
},
"rain": null,
"snow": null,
"clouds": {
"all": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 721,
"main": "Haze",
"description": "haze",
"icon": "50n"
}
]
}
]
}
```

how to get date and time?

Comment: `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=22.57&lon=88.37)&appid=(APP ID HERE)` will get you the unix time zone offset, sunrise and sunset in seconds.

Comment: `"dt": 1646658548` is the unix datetime in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try this API with your APP ID
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%20Oakland&appid=  //

you will get this JSON from API-

```
  {
       "coord":{
          "lon":-122.2708,
          "lat":37.8044
       },
       "weather":[
          {
             "id":801,
             "main":"Clouds",
             "description":"few clouds",
             "icon":"02n"
          }
       ],
       "base":"stations",
       "main":{
          "temp":279.3,
          "feels_like":277.8,
          "temp_min":274.84,
          "temp_max":282.85,
          "pressure":1026,
          "humidity":86
       },
       "visibility":10000,
       "wind":{
          "speed":2.06,
          "deg":60
       },
       "clouds":{
          "all":20
       },
       "dt":1646659485,
       "sys":{
          "type":2,
          "id":2042798,
          "country":"US",
          "sunrise":1646663524,
          "sunset":1646705301
       },
       "timezone":-28800,
       "id":5378538,
       "name":"Oakland",
       "cod":200
    }
```

or
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=%20Oakland&mode=json&units=imperial&appid=  //

you will get multiple data using this API.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. but from where did you get that link?

Comment: @Subhadeep98Ares I am using same paid version with my one client project. you can check API document of openweathermap for more details -https://openweathermap.org/current

Comment: is that paid link ? cause i am going to use it for my project.

Comment: No its free .I am using 10000 API calls so I have taken paid service.

Comment: its not working properly i guess @Sandesh

Comment: Which issue you will get in same?

Comment: i tried to convert timezone to date and time but it's not working. 
how did you implement this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242684/discussion-between-sandesh-and-subhadeep98ares).